# how to find linkbutton in a formview in order to write code for changing mode?

Tags: asp.net, formview

I have a web form which contains a formview(fv).
how can I find a linkbutton within it (lnkbtnEdit) in order to write code for changing mode?

thank you

Comment: I think the answer would depend upon **When** do you need to find the LinkButton. For example, On initial databinding? After postback ? You should also edit your question to include the markup of the FormView so that it is easier to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite vague so I'll try to make my answer as general as possible.

Container controls in ASP.NET provide a [FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.findcontrol.aspx) method which uses Reflection to locate the control with the specified name in their child controls. Using this method is the accepted method to locate controls within a Page or Panel or Templated control like the FormView.

If you want to avoid Reflection, you can also locate the control manually if you know the index of the control in the heirarchy.

Also, it is very helpful to know the point of time at which you need to access this control, because it is quite possible that the child control has not been created yet.(See my comment to your question.)

Answer (score 0):

Cerebus,
Thanks for your reply....
but it seems that I can not select the lnkbtnEdit within the fv. If I  could, then simply selected it in design view, and in event section of property window, I could write a handler for clicking it....